# YouTube API calls work when executed from py file but don't work in python interpreter

Tags: python, api, youtube

I am starting to be desperate.
I wanted to do some YouTube API testing and I've been getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The thing is, **I am trying to execute exactly the same code, which works when in py module**:

```
request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={
      "snippet": {
        "playlistId": playlistID,
        "position": position,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": videoID
        }
      }
    }
)
```

In both py file and python interpreter, I have initiated the youtube instance using

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

# Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
# *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = "MVYV_playlists.json"

# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

When I then call the following function in py code, it works

```
def playlist_add_video(videoID, position, playlistID):
  request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": playlistID,
            "position": position,
            "resourceId": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": videoID
            }
          }
        }
    )
  response = request.execute()
```

But when I do the following in the Python interpreter, it gives me that 2 arguments error

```
r = """part="snippet",
... body={
...     "snippet": {
...     "playlistId": "PLLT3d3KRQFTk3r4e-CWH8nUaK7J6X1WdS",
...     "position": 102,
...     "resourceId": {
...         "kind": "youtube#video",
...         "videoId": "8dVt7eE3BAo"
...     }
...     }
... }"""
request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(r)
```

I know it is somehow caused by Python automatically inserting **self** as the first parameter before the second parameter r.
I also know it is not connected with this specific youtube.playlistItems().insert() method, I tried it with others and the result was the same.
Is there any way to make it work in the interpreter? It would make my work flow much more effective. And I would really love to understand the reason of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you provided two kwargs arguments.
the method is requesting just one. I dont use this library nor have in my computer.
just try to do help(insert) or enter the implementation and check what are the arguments the method is exactly getting.